# Adding image to a "REGISTER" button messes up its register link. Why and how do I fix it? (Html and java)

Tags: html, button, authentication

I wanted to change the login and register buttons to two different images without messing up the login and register functions.

Here is the script:

```
<form method="POST" action="/?page=login&cmd=passme">
<p>
    <b>Email:</b><br>
    <input NAME="useremail" size="20" style="width:100px;">
</p>
<p>
    <b>Password:</b><br>
    <input TYPE="password" NAME="password" size="20" style="width:100px;">
</p> 
<p>
    <input type="submit" value="Login" name="B1" style="width: 60px; height: 22px";>
    <input type="button" value="Register now" name="B2" style='height: 22px' onclick="location.href='/?page=login&cmd=register'">
</p>
```

Thank you. I try to add input type=image but it messes up both functions: the login and the register function. I click on these buttons and it directs me to the failed login instead of the register page. Thank you very much.

Comment: HERE IS THE FULL SCRIPT:
</h4><form method="POST" action="/?page=login&cmd=passme"><p><b>Email:</b><br><input NAME="useremail" size="20" style="width:100px;"></p><p><b>Password:</b><br><input TYPE="password" NAME="password" size="20" style="width:100px;"></p>

<p><input type="submit" value="Login" name="B1" src='IMAGEpngorjpeg' style="width: 60px; height: 22px";><input type="button" value="Register now" name="B2" src='imagepngorjpeg' style='width: 60px; height: 22px' onclick="location.href='/?page=login&cmd=register'"></p></form>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make your buttons of type image. These also submit forms. Add return false for your onclick event to stop the form submission (that is why it goes to login instead of register).

```
<form method="POST" action="/?page=login&cmd=passme">
    <p>
        <b>Email:</b><br>
        <input NAME="useremail" size="20" style="width:100px;">
    </p>
    <p>
        <b>Password:</b><br>
        <input TYPE="password" NAME="password" size="20" style="width:100px;">
    </p> 
    <p>
        <input type="image" src="http://www.codetoad.com/images/submit_button.gif" value="Login" name="B1" style="width: 60px; height: 22px";>
        <input type="image" src="http://libn.com/wp-files/graphics/register-button_0.jpg" value="Register now" name="B2" style='height: 22px' onclick="location.href='/?page=login&cmd=register'; return false">
    </p>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that did it! I have two quick questions if you don't mind: 1)Members of my site will still be able to login with their email and password and register if they haven't done so, correct? Just want to make sure that these images do not change any function or cause errors. 2) The return false should make the onclick go void, instead goes right to the link specified, why is that? Thanks again. I voted your answer, very helpful.

Comment: Using images does change the way the form submits. How you handle this depends on your server side code. The return false tells the form not to submit.